# Lodash _.reduce issue?

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I was wondering if anyone could show me what I'm doing wrong here, I'm trying to use _.reduce to get the fields in an object and it seems to be missing the 'first' one every time.

The first line here is plain old js, the next is lodash.

```
$scope.actualKeys = Object.keys($scope.item);
_.reduce($scope.item, function(result, value, key) {
  $scope.keys.push(key);
});
```

Where $scope.item is

```
$scope.item = {
field1: 'test',
field2: 'test',
field3: 'test',
field4: 'test',
field5: 'test',
field6: 'test'
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/J9MBahQNIsZkMFzrHjKG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.forEach()` instead of `_.reduce()` ([plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/05lghqyGRPqIICXY5903?p=preview)):

```
_.forEach($scope.item, function(value, key) {
  $scope.keys.push(key);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's missing the first element, I'm going to hazard a guess that since you haven't set an initial accumulator, it's using the first element as the initial accumulator, then starting the fold on the second element.

Note, I don't know lodash; this is just standard reduce behavior. Look up the documention to see how to set an initial accumulator.

Setting an initial accumulator is usually a good idea, unless you know for sure the list will never be empty. Without setting it, trying to reduce an empty list will either throw, or return `undefined` (depending on the behaviour of lodash). Without accounting for these failures, you may get a surprise down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an accumulator it will work.

```
$scope.actualKeys = Object.keys($scope.item);
_.reduce($scope.item, function(result, value, key) {
    $scope.keys.push(key);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A reduce function is used to reduce a collection down to a single value. Each time through it accumulates based on the previous value, hence your problem with the first. In other words, while you can make it work (as others have shown), it's the wrong tool for the job.

What you need in this case is a simple loop (or, as you already know, `Object.keys`).